# Force user to enter affirm or deny text intent in Rasa Chatbot

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I have a story and I want that the user enters affirm OR deny intent, and if not, for example, repeat the same previous bot-message and continue to the next step only when the user enters intent of type affirm or deny.

How to do that without buttons?
as soon as possible, please.

as below my principal path story:

**checking_coronavirus_path1** 
-wichCheckCoronavirus 
utter_ask_fievre 
-affirm OR deny 
action_save_intent_and_user_message 
utter_ask_cough 
-affirm OR deny 
action_save_intent_and_user_message 
utter_ask_fatigue 
-affirm OR deny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be with a form. You can find [the Rasa 1.0 documentation here](https://legacy-docs-v1.rasa.com/core/forms/); the "outdoor_seating" slot is set with a yes/no question so you can use that as an example.